# How do I fix connectivity issues in Ordnance Survey Mastermap Highways Network

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, network-analyst, network-dataset, os-mastermap

I have created a network dataset in ArcGIS Pro using Ordnance Survey Mastermap Highways Network (Roads and Paths) but I am unable to get the connectivity to exist between the roads and paths.

This should be done via the Connecting Link features, however the connectivity does not seem to work between these features and the road links, even when specifying 'any vertex' connectivity.

The screenshots below demonstrate an example along with analysis of the connectivity at these points for a simple travel mode with no restrictions.

Roads (Grey lines)
Connecting Links (Black lines)
Paths (dashed lines)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to force connectivity or is this a known issue with these datasets?

Comment: Looks like your missing the RoadLink information. see (ESRI parts) https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/documents/osmm-highways-network-getting-started-guide.pdf

Comment: @Mapperz Thank you, do you just mean the RoadLink feature class? If so, I do have this, it is the grey road lines I referenced above, with the network connectivity check on the third screenshot. Apologies if this was not clear.